# Random number between two user inputs

Tags: python, function, numbers, generator

I've got a working code for a random number generator in python between two user inputs, like 1 and 10, but I need to add a `def` function somewhere in the code. For a project on understanding `def` functions.

```
x=input("enter 1st number: ")
x=int(x)
c=input("enter 2nd number: ")
c=int(c)
import random
b= random.randrange(c,x) 
print("========================")
print("in between numbers below")
print("========================")
print(b)
```

Comment: Why not add `def f(): return "hello"` somewhere and you're done?

Comment: I have to make the code above with a def function involved with the subject

Comment: Okay, why not indent your existing code and write `def f():` above it?

Comment: that could work, could you show me an example?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation.

Answer (score 1):

your function worked nicely.I just made a couple of adjustments to the code so its clearer which one goes first and put it in the function.

```py
import random
def random_number_generator():
    """
    function that generates random number from a range that is specified by user
    """
    first_number = int(input("enter 1st number(smaller number): "))
    second_number = int(input("enter 2st number(larger number): "))
    generate_random_number = random.randrange(first_number,second_number) 
    print("========================")
    print("in between numbers below")
    print("========================")
    return generate_random_number

random_number_generator()
```

Comment: thank you, I'm having trouble getting your code to ask the user to input their numbers.

Comment: it worked well for me, just tried it again. did you run it? random_number_generator()